# Computing the residue of given function and appliance of residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

Given the function: \begin{align*} f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{i,i+\frac{1}{\pi} \right\} \to \mathbb{C}, \quad z\mapsto \cos\left(\frac{1}{z-i}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{z-i-\frac{1}{\pi}} \end{align*}
**1.** I am supposed to find the maximal open pointed disc around $i$, such that the Laurent series of f around i converges and compute $res(f,i)$. 
**2.** Furthermore, there's $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{C},\,t\mapsto 2e^{it}$ and I should compute $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$.
So for the second part of my question I am pretty sure I can use the residue theorem, since $f$ is holomorphic on the Ball of radius $1/\pi$ and center i. $\{i\}$ is a discrete and therfore I should be able to compute the integral by \begin{align} \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=2\pi i \cdot res(i,f)\cdot n(i,\gamma). \end{align}Now comes the tricky part. I could use the residue computed by the first part, but I have difficulties doing so. I think I am supposed to first compute the laurent series and the just take the coefficient $a_{-1}$. First of all I think the laurent series converges on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z-i|< \frac{1}{\pi}\}$ since f is holomorphic and there is an isolated singularity at $i+\frac{1}{\pi}$. But now I got stuck computing the laurent series: 
By the series representation of the cosine and the series expansion of the second function I got: \begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k!} ((z-i)^{-2})^k \cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \pi^{k+1} (z-i)^k .\end{align}
From there, I can just look at the laurent series an then get the residue.
Is this even the right idea? Do you have any tips how to compute the product of the to series?

Comment: There is a big difference between $\,\cos(\frac{1}{z-i})\,$ and $\,1/\cos(z-i).\,$ The first has an **essential** singularity at $\,z=i\,$ while the second is holomorphic there.

Comment: @Somos that‘s true but as far as I‘m concerned i did the right thing.

Comment: My point is that you can't get the power series exapnsion of $\,\cos(\frac1{z-i})\,$ at $\,z=i\,$ as you have attempted to do.

Comment: @Somos That's the power series of $\cos (1/(z-i))$ and the series expansion of the other function at $z=i$. Sorry if that wasn't clear. The first function is already the expansion of $\cos(1/z)$ at $z=i$.

Comment: I found $a_{-1}=1$. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to determine the region of convergence and to calculate the residue at $z=i$ is sound. Expansion of $f$ at $z=i$ gives
\begin{align*}
f(z)
&=\cos\left(\frac{1}{z-i}\right)\frac{1}{(z-i)-\frac{1}{\pi}}\\
&=\cos\left(\frac{1}{z-i}\right)\frac{-\pi}{1-\pi(z-i)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\,\frac{1}{(z-i)^{2k}}
(-\pi)\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\pi^l(z-i)^l\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We don't need to calculate the product of the series in (1). Since we just need to calculate $\mathrm{res}_{z=i}f(z)$, it is sufficient to calculate the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-i}$ of the product. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{res}_{z=i}f(z)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}(-\pi)\pi^{2k-1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k)!}\pi^{2k}\\
> &=-\cos(\pi)+1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2}
> \end{align*}